# Problems embed IronPython in C# game for scripting

Tags: c#-4.0, ironpython

I am currently trying to embed this project [xna console](http://xnaconsole.codeplex.com/) in my game but I am having problems with the IronPython Interpreter.

The problem am having is with the following code

```
this.PythonOutput = new MemoryStream();
ScriptingEngine.pyEngine.SetStandardOutput(PythonOutput); // this line is giving me an error 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine' does not contain a definition for 'SetStandardOutput' and no extension method 'SetStandardOutput' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine' could be found
this.ASCIIEncoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
```

and the second problem am having is with this code

```
ClrModule clr = ScriptingEngine.pyEngine.Import("clr") as ClrModule;
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework");
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game");
```

Am getting issues with the ClrModule cannot declare a variable of static type 'IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule also the Import is giving me errors Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine does not contain a definition for 'Import'

Am using IronPython version 2.7.1 and .net4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetStandardOutput has moved onto the IO property on ScriptRuntime I believe instead of ScriptEngine.

ClrModule is a static class, so if you need to call AddReference on it you can call it using ClrModule.AddReference(codeContext, ...).  You can search for how to get a code context, but a better way might be:

dynamic clr = pyEngine.Import("clr");
clr.AddReference(...);